# JavaScript code not working,can't hide/show div contents

Tags: javascript, html, hide, element, show

New to Stack Overflow and JavaScript as a whole.

I've been trying to make a simple function that changes the inline display attribute of a few div elements on click from "none" to "block". Tried different bits of code from similar questions on here,but no luck with any of them. Here's the code. Am sorry if I didn't format it correctly :(

**Code:**

```js
function toggleMenuItem(subGroupId) {
  subGroupIdStyle = document.getElementById('subGroupId').style;

  var see = subGroupIdStyle.display;
  if (see == 'none') {
    see = 'block';
  } else {
    see = 'none';
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p id="title">Computer <br>components</p>
  <p id="item1" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup1');">CPUs</p>
  <div id="subgroup1" style="display:none;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Intel</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">AMD</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">ARM</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">nVidia</a>
  </div>

  <p id="item2" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup2');">Motherboards</p>
  <div id="subgroup2" style="display:none;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Asus</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Asrock</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Foxconn</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Gigabyte</a>
  </div>

  <p id="item3" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup3');">Memory</p>
  <div id="subgroup3" style="display:none;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Samsung</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">A-Data</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Corsair</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Kingston</a>
  </div>

  <p id="item4" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup4');">Hard Drives</p>
  <div id="subgroup4" style="display:none;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Western Digital</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Seagate</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Toshiba</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Hitachi</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're just changing the value of variable `see`. You need to update the `style` of element in DOM. Use `document.getElementById('subGroupId').style.display = see === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';`.

Comment: I'll suggest you to create a class `.hide { display: none; }` in CSS and toggle it using `.classList.toggle('hide');`

Comment: Issue is you are just copying value of a property. So when you updated that variable, it will not affect property in Object. @Tushar's comment is the apt way, but if you are not familiar with ternary operators, try using `subGroupIdStyle.display` instead of `see` in both `if` and `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the variable when you wrap it in ' '

```
subGroupIdStyle = document.getElementById(subGroupId).style;
```

remove '' in subGroupId, that way you actually pass the variable string.

Also, instead of doing `see = 'block';` do `subGroupIdStyle.display = 'block'`, same for else condition.

The code `see = 'block'` is not working because, you just copied the value of the subGroupIdStyle.display at the time, while you can use it to check the value, when you change the value of `see` it is not going to change the value of `subGroupIdStyle.display`. You should avoid using `see` altogether and use `subGroupIdStyle.display` in the place.

```js
function toggleMenuItem(subGroupId) {

  subGroupIdStyle = document.getElementById(subGroupId).style;
  var see = subGroupIdStyle.display;

  if (see == 'none') {
   subGroupIdStyle.display = 'block';
  }
  else { 
    subGroupIdStyle.display = 'none'; 
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p id="title">Computer <br>components</p>
  <p id="item1" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup1');">CPUs</p> 
    <div id="subgroup1" style="display:none;">
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Intel</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">AMD</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">ARM</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">nVidia</a>
    </div>

  <p id="item2" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup2');">Motherboards</p> 
    <div id="subgroup2" style="display:none;">
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Asus</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Asrock</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Foxconn</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Gigabyte</a>
    </div> 

  <p id="item3" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup3');">Memory</p> 
    <div id="subgroup3" style="display:none;">
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Samsung</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">A-Data</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Corsair</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Kingston</a>
    </div> 

  <p id="item4" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup4');">Hard Drives</p> 
    <div id="subgroup4" style="display:none;">
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Western Digital</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Seagate</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Toshiba</a> <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Hitachi</a>
   </div> 
    
 </div>
```

Comment: Please check other answer as this(*remove quotes*) has been covered already. And for replacing `see`. please add explanation as to why its not working with `see`

Comment: @Rajesh, yes I did that.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly now! wrapping ' ' around a function's parameter doesn't pass the variable correctly,right? or am I missing something again?

Comment: @Pete, when you wrapped the variable's name in quotes, it no longer is the variable, it becomes a String, so you were passing 'subGroupId' in the function, no matter what was being clicked.

Comment: @Pete, I suggest you use Firebug, or any debugger while writing code, you'll be able to see active variable's values and much more, and it will help you understand greatly what is happening in the background. Also, select a correct answer if your problem is solved by any of the answers below.

Comment: @SacredSatan Care to suggest me a good alternative to Firebug for Chrome?The built-in dev tools are throwing me some weird file_not_found errors on an image gallery im trying to make,not really explaining whats wrong with the code or anything else that might be remotely helpful :(

Comment: @Pete, take a look at this [Google Developers | Debugging JavaScript in Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
subGroupIdStyle = document.getElementById('subGroupId').style;
```

**change to**

```
subGroupIdStyle = document.getElementById(subGroupId).style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use single line `if` condition .Variable passing  was wrong.you are applying string instead of passing variable. you could use like this

```
                document.getElementById(subGroupId)
```

And `see = 'block';` is not overwrite the element style.so you could use full of the style like `variable.style.display="block"`

```js
function toggleMenuItem(subGroupId) {
  var subGroupIdStyle = document.getElementById(subGroupId);
  subGroupIdStyle.style.display = (subGroupIdStyle.style.display =='none')?'block':'none';

}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p id="title">Computer <br>components</p>
  <p id="item1" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup1');">CPUs</p>
  <div id="subgroup1" style="display:none;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Intel</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">AMD</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">ARM</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">nVidia</a>
  </div>

  <p id="item2" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup2');">Motherboards</p>
  <div id="subgroup2" style="display:none;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Asus</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Asrock</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Foxconn</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Gigabyte</a>
  </div>

  <p id="item3" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup3');">Memory</p>
  <div id="subgroup3" style="display:none;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Samsung</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">A-Data</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Corsair</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Kingston</a>
  </div>

  <p id="item4" class="menuitem" onclick="toggleMenuItem('subgroup4');">Hard Drives</p>
  <div id="subgroup4" style="display:none;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Western Digital</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Seagate</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Toshiba</a> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; + <a href="#" class="submenu">Hitachi</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistake:

1- You shouldn't wrap the variable subGroupId in quote.

2- You can not change style of dom by:

```
  var see = subGroupIdStyle.display;
  if (see == 'none') {
    see = 'block';
  } else {
    see = 'none';
  }
```

use

> `subGroupIdStyle.display = 'block';`